# Best pattern to update list of items in database

Tags: mysql, database

What is the best pattern (in terms of average performance) to update the list of items stored in some database?

For example, some user works with table which consists of N rows. He can delete all rows and then add M rows with totally different data, or he can update just one character of one field in one row.

Now we remove all existing rows with `DELETE` query and then `INSERT` new rows without considering how much data was changed.

Do any more effective patterns exist for this case?

**UPDATE:**

We also have considered 2 alternative approaches:

1) At the beggining of updating transaction do `SELECT`, analyze which rows are updated/deleted/added and apply appropriate changes to DB.

2) Make user interface interactive and send AJAX-request with changed data for every user's action - then mark appropriate rows as changed.

Comment: truncate + bulk insert? What is N rows?

Comment: @L-Three In our case N is not so much - about hundeds of rows - but it is interesting to now answer for general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch insert,update and delete will be best.In case of hitting the database for every insert,update and delete you can perform batch operation.So in case of performance the round trip for every insert and update will be minimized.As you can insert data in a bulk ,so that the data base hit will be minimized